# Calling View with Parameters using AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

So I have a `AJAX` function which calls a view in the controller with parameters. As I debug everything works fine and also i get the correct results returned, but the page is not reloaded in the browser. I'm using the `AJAX` to apply a filter to a list, but now the view get set up correct but no reload/refresh of the list in the browser. And when I then reload by myself, I get the list without the filter. (which makes sense)

For example: I have a list with cats and dogs and apply the filter just for dogs I still got cats in my list after the ajax call has finished. I searched a long time for an answer to this but have not found one jet.

Also adding  a `location.reload();` in the success function does not work since the view is then called with other parameters then set in the `AJAX` call.

So I just want to have a `AJAX` call which calls the view with the `p_applicationId` as a parameter and them shows the view which was called via `AJAX`

**AJAX**

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#applicationDropdown").change(function () {
        var releaseId = $("#applicationDropdown").val();
        var filterReport = $("#filterReport");
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: '@Url.Action("Index", "ProductionDeployment")',
             data: { p_applicationId: releaseId },
            success: function (data)
            {
                filterReport.html('Success, The Releases have been filtered.');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                filterReport.html('Failed to filter the Releases. ' + thrownError);
                //  alert('Failed to filter the Releases.', xhr, thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**ProductionDeploymentController.cs**

```
public class ProductionDeploymentController : BaseController
{
    // Variable Initialisation
    DBhandler dbhandler = new DBhandler();
    string cnnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conChdbd1"].ConnectionString;
    string sqlStr;

    /// <summary>
    /// GET: ProductionDeployment
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> Function Return View </returns>
    public ActionResult Index(String p_applicationId)
    {
        if (p_applicationId == null)
        {
            p_applicationId = "CTTS";
        }
        PrepareViewBagJustApplication();
        List<ProductionPending> pendingDeployments = GetPendingProductionDeployments(p_applicationId);
        ProductionDeployments pd = new ProductionDeployments();
        pd.Pending = pendingDeployments;
        return View(pd);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function contains a SQL which links to a Package, which is sent to the DBHandler and returns a DataTable,
    /// The DataTable then is then converted into a List<> in the ConvertTo...() function and passed back to the View.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> List of Pending Productions: List<ProductionPending> </returns>
    private List<ProductionPending> GetPendingProductionDeployments(String p_applicationId)
    {
        List<ProductionPending> list = null;
        sqlStr = "ADM_PORTAL_REP.p_PendingProdDeployments";
        DataTable dt = dbhandler.ExecuteQuery(sqlStr, "2016-04", p_applicationId);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            list = ConvertToProductionPending(dt).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            list = new List<ProductionPending>();
            list.Clear();
        }
        return list;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to convert the DataTable sent in into an IEnumerable<ProductionPending> 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dt"></param>
    /// <returns> IEnumerable of Pending Productions: IEnumerable<ProductionPending> </returns>
    private IEnumerable<ProductionPending> ConvertToProductionPending(DataTable dt)
    {
        return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
        {
            return new ProductionPending
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]),
                releaseId = row["releaseId"].ToString(),
                RFCNumber = Convert.ToInt32(row["RFCNumber"]),
                developerInitials = row["developerInitials"].ToString(),
                fileName = row["fileName"].ToString(),
                fileVersion = row["fileVersion"].ToString(),
                RFDNumber = Convert.ToInt32(row["RFDNumber"]),
                desiredDeploymentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["desiredDeploymentDate"]),
                deploymentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["deploymentDate"]),
                notes = row["notes"].ToString(),
                detailNotes = row["detailNotes"].ToString(),
                approvedInd = row["approvedInd"].ToString(),
                dateRequested = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dateRequested"]),
                applicationId = row["application"].ToString(),
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. You have your data. You need to do something with it. Your js code gets it and ... throws it away.

Comment: See what you did with `filterReport.html('Success, The Releases have been filtered.');`? You need to do something similar, but with `data` passed into the function instead.

Comment: Okayy thanks, Ill give it a try